part number when it is not ecu part?
Is the oem part number the same as all the other stores part numbers?
And by different manufacturers.?
The part I’m speaking of has two part numbers on it a part # and an alternate part #.?
Wich one would interchange? With the oem part #?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you searching for a specific ECU? What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

Your mileage may vary.
There is no part number per se. There is a part number from a particular part catalogue.
If the part is used by different car makers and/or produced by different OEMs, it may as well end up with 20 different numbers. OEMs usually list all of them, car makers usually stick to their own.
When one looks for a replacement, usually, but not always, any of the part numbers related to this part will do.
The exceptions happen when some part is backwards compatible (can be used on newer and older models), but the older part cannot be used in the newer models.
